# Get information from a Ghost.py file

Tags: python, ghost.py

i am doing a project in which i need to get the information from webpages.
i am using python and ghost for it.
i saw this code in the documentation:

```
links = gh.evaluate("""
                    var linksobj = document.querySelectorAll("a");
                    var links = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<linksobj.length; i++){
                        links.push(linksobj[i].value);
                    }
                    links;
                """)
```

this code is definitely not python. which language is it and where i can learn how to configure it?
how can find a string from the tags eg.
in:

```
title>this is title of the webpage
```

how can i get

```
this is title of the page
```

thanks.

Comment: If the output you receive is a string then I think you should have a look at the common string operations in python. You can strip, split and do a lot of things with a string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: looks like javascript

Comment: @PadraicCunningham your analysis seems correct to me too.

Comment: i want to get string from<title>STRING</title>. when i posted the question i tried to post it like this but it automatically skipped title tags.

Comment: @user1934948 my answer gets the string.

Comment: i did used beautiful soup at the beginning but it cannot handle javascript that's why i shifted to ghost.

Comment: @user1934948 you asked how could you get <title>STRING</title>, that is not javascript.

Comment: You can use json with BeautifulSoup to parse javascript also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) is a webkit client. It allows you to load a web page and interact with its DOM and runtime.

This means that once you have everything installed and running, you can simply do this:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, resources = ghost.open('http://stackoverflow.com/')
if page.http_status == 200:
    result, extra = ghost.evaluate('document.title;')
    print('The title is: {}'.format(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup.title.string
In [3]: soup.title.string
Out[3]: u'Google'
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the person's problem since he is not using requests or beautifulsoup.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, he is using python where both are available. Maybe the OP does not know about them or do we presume every SO member knows of all libs?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After looking at the answer from Padraic Cunningham, it seems to me that I unfortunately misunderstood your question. Any how I leave my answer for future references or maybe for downvotes. :P

If the output you receive is a string then common string operations in python to achieve the desired output you mentioned in your question.

You receive : `title>this is title of the webpage`

You desire: `this is title of the webpage`

Assuming that the output you receive is always in the same format so you can do following string operation to get your desired output.
Using [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) operation:

```
>>> s = 'title>this is title of the webpage'
>>> p = s.split('>')
>>> p
 ['title', 'this is title of the webpage']
>>> p[1]
'this is title of the webpage'
```

Here `p` is a list so you have to access its proper element that contains your desired output.

Or more simpler way is to make a substring.

```
>>> s = 'title>this is title of the webpage'
>>> p = s[6:]
>>> p
'this is title of the webpage'
```

`p = s[6:]` in the above code snippet means that you want a string which has all the contents of `title>this is title of the webpage` starting from 7th element to the end. In other words you are ignoring the first `6` elements.

If the output you receive is not always in the same format then you may prefer using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Your second question is already answered in the comments section. 
I hope I understood your questions correctly.